# What are the differences between Defense of the Ancients (DotA) and League of Legends (LoL)?

Tags: league-of-legends, dota

I played a lot to League of Legends (>1000 hours) and I am going to try DotA now. Speaking about **gameplay** only, it would be really helpful for a newbie knowing what are the main differences between `Defense of the Ancients` (DotA) and `League of Legends` (LoL)?

Comment: VTC as per [this meta](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/2853/whats-the-difference-between-fortresscraft-and-minecraft-who-cares)

Comment: VTC needs a reason that says: should be on Wikipedia.  Then again, they don't seem to like anything over there...

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Some of the most noticeable changes that pertain to League of Legends:

- Champion selection is limited to the "free to play" champions (which are rotated on a weekly basis) or the ones you have purchased using in game points (Influence points) or real life money (converted into Riot points).
- Maximum level is 18. With the exception of (as of writing this) 2 champions, Udyr and Karma, this gives your Q, W, and E skills 5 levels, and your R ultimate 3 levels. For Udyr, as he has no true ult, but rather 4 basic skills, you could have a 5 5 5 3 setup, or a 5 5 4 4 setup, or any combination therein. For Karma, her ult is given at level 1 and never levels up, giving her Q, W and E skills 6 levels each.
- No denying. This includes towers
  as well as creeps/minions. You can still deny by keeping enemy champions out of the kill radius / prevent them from last hitting, but there is no "auto-attack your own minions" to deny.
- No gold loss on death.
- Towers hit a lot harder and do more
  damage to you the longer they've been
  hitting you, making early tower dives
  a lot riskier and making towers much
  safer to defend against.
- You can kill the enemy base/nexus
  without having to kill the 3 inner
  lane turrets. You still must kill the
  2 nexus towers first, however.
- The ranged/melee barracks have been
  merged into a single building called
  an inhibitor, and instead of
  bolstering the melee/ranged minions
  in that lane when destroyed, it
  instead makes a single, powerful
  melee unit spawn with every wave.
  Inhibitors respawn over time.
- There are far fewer "active" items
  (click to use) and the focus is more
  on increasing your passive stats.
- Every champion has a passive ability
  that is somewhat integral to their
  playstyle or their character flavor.
  These passives are always active and
  require no skill points. For example,
  the champion Zilean increases all
  allies' experience gain by 8% always. A more active example would be the character LeBlanc, who spawns a mirror image whenever she drops below 40% HP (occuring at most once per minute).
- There is a 3v3 as well as a 5v5 map,
  meaning there are two separate
  meta-games to identify (though most
  people play 5v5).
- Some of the larger neutral creeps
  provide passive buffs that provide a
  visual effect as well as a bonus to
  attributes. For example, the Golem
  buff provides mana/energy
  regeneration and cool down reduction.
- There is a large neutral creep called
  the dragon that provides teamwide
  gold and experience. This is often
  contested through the mid-late game
  and is a prime target for jungler
  champions to kill.
- The "boss" neutral creep (Baron
  Nashtor) does not provide an item
  (like Token of Life), but rather
  teamwide gold/exp and a passive buff
  that greatly increases
  health/mana/energy regen as well as
  additional attack damage and ability
  power.
- You get to choose 2 additional
  "Summoner Abilities" that are
  universal regardless of what champion
  you pick. Some examples of these are
  Ghost (temporary speed boost and
  unitwalking), Flash (short range
  teleport), Ignite (scaling damage
  with a DoT and reduced healing/regen
  component), and Clairvoyance (short
  cooldown, small radius map reveal).
  There are others too, of course.
- No river runes.
- You may passively increase your
  champions' stats by purchasing
  "Runes" outside of the actual in-game
  interface. These runes are purchased
  using points you earn by playing
  games (winning or losing).
- Additionally, you may increase your champions stats / enhance your "Summoner Abilities" / provide passive effects through the mastery system. The mastery system is a simplified version of a talent tree (akin to Diablo 2, World of Warcraft, etc.) with points being earned as you level your summoner (your account), which is done by simply playing games.
- Ability to return to base (free, no need to buy it, no item slot taken, no cooldown)
- Improved juking - instead of sneaky paths between trees there is "brush" (bushes/grass) system - brush blocks line of sight of those outside it and provides bonuses to some champions/heroes
- Map is symmetrical with the exception of the placement of the Dragon and Baron "boss" creeps.
- Shields system - damage shields are dynamically displayed as a gray extension of the healthbars. Purple extensions indicate magic-only shields.
- It's possible to bind smartcasts (cast instantly on keypress on the area the cursor is hovering over, not on an additional mouse click)
- No secret shops or outposts. All items are purchased at the base shop.
- The Shop's combination items are displayed in a tree, making it easy to see which items combine into what.

I'll add more as I think of more. Hope this is a good start for you!

Comment: Pretty Comprehensive;  I'd add the hero selection being more limited unless you unlock heroes.

Comment: You might want to make it clear what game you are talking about, TheQ.  Also, I don't think it's correct to say Denying isn't present in LoL, since you can still deny last hits via smart harassment and of course summoner kills.  But there's no "active" deny where you last hit your own creeps.

Comment: @GWL Good point. I wouldn't say that falls under "gameplay" as Drake requested, but I'll add it anyway.

Comment: @peacedog I'll add in that I'm referring to LoL, and while you're correct about denying in that regard, I think that term is mostly reserved for the active form of killing your own creeps. I'll add in a clause there.

Comment: @TheQ Do you know if in DOTA you can buy an item and then give it to one of your teammates?

Comment: @Drake Not sure in DOTA, honestly, but I believe so. In HON you can. In LoL you cannot.

Comment: @Drake Only for consumable and some regeneration items, and they can't upgrade those items. It's mostly just sharing for the laning phase, not buying for use.

Comment: @TheQ Link is dead, Riot probably didn't want it to be explicitly clear to its users that they are the copy, not the other way around. -.-

Comment: @Decency Thanks for the heads up, removing said link.

Comment: This seems a bit like it's written for people who already know a lot about DotA, but I'd like to know more about what DotA does.  What is a river rune?

Answer (score 9):

<strike>[Riot's own words](http://www.leagueoflegends.com/learn/dota_and_lol).</strike> *since removed*

Updated link: http://web.archive.org/web/20110803192258/http://na.leagueoflegends.com/learn/dota_and_lol

The two games are mostly very similar -- Riot wanted to make a game very much like DotA but on a standalone engine. The Warcraft 3 map engine provided many limitations in creating a balanced experience, such as handling disconnects, rage quitting penalties, etc.

Comment: Thank you for the link, useful but I would like to hear the voice of people that played both in order to understand big but even small differences about gameplay between these two games.

Comment: @Drake understood; unfortunately I only play LoL, having had very limited experience with DotA.